# Why redirection to a while loop doesn't print the messages?

Tags: command-line, tail

Here is a shell code used to track changes in a file and output the content to the terminal:

```
while read LINE
do
  echo $LINE
done < `tail -f /var/log/messages`
```

It doesn't work, why?

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: @P.-H.Lin It just output nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for a while loop. You try to do two times the same. Also the file `/var/log/messages` is not present in ubuntu anymore.

Just use:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

to track new content that is added at the end of the text file. If something new is written to the end of `/var/log/syslog` it is printed to your terminal.

**Edit: Why the command in the question doesn't work:**

First, of course, `/var/log/messages` does not exist. But if it would exist, the command between backticks is executed and replaced by its output (minus the trailing newline characters). So the output of `tail -f ...` would be taken as filename for the input redirection `<`. What you probably want would look as follows (the the `<(...)` redirection):

```
while read LINE; do
  echo $LINE
done < <(tail -f /var/log/messages)
```

The `<(...)` redirection creates a named pipe, where on one end the command `tail -f` writes to. On the other end the `while` loop reads the contents line by line. A named pipe behaves likely to a regular file. It is just a connection piece between two commands. BTW, the `|` does exactly the same, but those pipe are not named, they are the default channels: 0 -> stdin, 1 -> stdout and 2 -> stderr.

From the `bash` manpage:

```
 Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the 
 /dev/fd method of naming open files. It takes the form of <(list) or >(list).
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about this

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But I'm curious why the code in OP doesn't work. `tail` redirects the content in the file to the `while` loop and `echo` should output the content, but in fact, it output nothing. Would you mind explain why?

Comment: Because "/var/log/messages" does not exist and if it does it does not get written to since it is become obsolete.

Comment: @MarkZar see my edit

Comment: chaos, i think process substitution creates anonymous pipes, not named pipes..note that named pipes are not removed automatically after a task is complete whereas process substitution removes the anonymous pipe it creates during operation..

Comment: @heemayl anonymous pipes are created from the `|` as far as I know. `<()` creates a named pipe. See `ls -l <(true)`; prints `/dev/fd/xx`, that's a named pipe.

Comment: @heemayl I made a reference in the answer to the manual page of bash, with the definition.

Comment: chaos, it is still confusing to me....check this http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156088/68757

Comment: @heemayl Hm, we have different sources, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution#Mechanism

Comment: @heemayl BTW: all pipes are named (also the anonymous ones), because they are represented somewhere in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The usual portable way of doing this is:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages | while read LINE
do
  echo $LINE
done
```

@chaos's answer is using process substitution syntax which is only found in advanced shells such as `zsh` and `bash`. You should not rely on their features if you ever need to run your script on a different computer.

Of course, I assume that you want to put something more complex than `echo $LINE` into the loop.

Comment: Much portable, on the other hand... it doesn't work on Ubuntu: `/var/log/messages` is not present anymore

Comment: @kos sir how it is more portable?

Comment: No no it is portable, I'm not complaining about that. The problem is it doesn't work on Ubuntu, and this is Ask Ubuntu. You should change `/var/log/messages` with `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: But why to pipe the output of `tail` in a while loop which just prints the output? `tail -f file` without the loop is enough.

Comment: @chaos Did you read the last paragraph?